# C++ [[noreturn]] function call and destructors

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, att, noreturn

I have some C++ code in which I must be sure that a specific destructor is called before exiting and I was wondering whether or not it was called before a [[noreturn]] function.

So I wrote this simple dummy example

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
class A {
        char *i;
public:
        A() : i{new char[4]} {}
        ~A() { delete[] i; }
        void hello() { puts(i); }
};

int func()
{
        A b;
        exit(1);
        b.hello(); // Not reached
}
```

I compiled with `g++ /tmp/l.cc -S -O0` and I got this assembly

```
    .file   "l.cc"
    .text
    .section    .text._ZN1AC2Ev,"axG",@progbits,_ZN1AC5Ev,comdat
    .align 2
    .weak   _ZN1AC2Ev
    .type   _ZN1AC2Ev, @function
_ZN1AC2Ev:
.LFB18:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $4, %edi
    call    _Znam
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, (%rax)
    nop
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE18:
    .size   _ZN1AC2Ev, .-_ZN1AC2Ev
    .weak   _ZN1AC1Ev
    .set    _ZN1AC1Ev,_ZN1AC2Ev
    .text
    .globl  func
    .type   func, @function
func:
.LFB24:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    leaq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZN1AC1Ev
    movl    $1, %edi
    call    exit
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE24:
    .size   func, .-func
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 12.2.1 20221121 (Red Hat 12.2.1-4)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

There was clearly no call to the destructor.

In this stupid case it doesn't matter much, but what if I had to close a file before exiting?

Comment: For one calling `exit()` is about the rudest way of terminating a program. It is better to throw an exception and allow for all objects to go out of scope before or at the exit of main. And access resources through RAII classes (like std::ifstream). They will be destructed and cleanup resource (close files). For the rest, like real crashes there is nothing you can really do (and the OS will cleanup left overs for you)

Comment: Maybe you want [`std::atexit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) and [`std::at_quick_exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/at_quick_exit) then?

Comment: Also don't use new/delete if you don't have to use std::vector which is one of those RAII classes that will free memory when properly deleted.

Comment: *but what if I had to close a file before exiting?* - Then you should have used `atexit`, or should have avoided `exit()` before the necessary work was done.  `[[noreturn]]` doesn't change the semantics of when destructors are called.

Comment: Your OS will cleanup the resources in that case. Ugly, but will fly

Comment: @tilz0R: If there was any unwritten data in an output buffer, it would get lost.  "closing" at the level of a C++ `iostream` can include flushing write buffers, not just OS-level `close()` of a file descriptor.  Could also imply renaming a temporary file to atomically replace a file if you were doing that instead of truncating the original, or of deleting the temporary file on a bad exit.  If it was just an OS-level `close` system call you wanted to do before exit, yes that is superfluous.

Comment: @dVNE: your asm would be a significantly easier to read with demangled names and without the noise of `.cfi` and other directives.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) .  e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/rKezcv4zv .  Your test-case only calls `delete` in the destructor; a more visible side-effect like `puts` there as well would make it more obvious, and not be subject to optimizing away if it was allowed to happen before the end of the function.

Comment: @PeterCordes I felt that [[noreturn]] should also change the semantics of the program. I think it is what a programmer would expect. As for the optimizations I compiled with -O0

Comment: I assumed it would just be a portable version of GNU C's `__attribute__((noreturn))`, which lets the compiler know how (for optimization and warning purposes) that execution doesn't continue after it.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-noreturn-function-attribute .  Unfortunately in this case your expectations didn't line up with the committee's decision about what `[[noreturn]]` should do.

Comment: "I must be sure that a specific destructor is called before exiting" https://thedailywtf.com/articles/my-tales

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the fact that terminating a program with `exit()` is generally considered bad practice, you could try the following:

```cpp
int func()
{
    {
        A b;
        /* ... */
    } // Leaving scope => destructing b
    exit(1);
}
```

PS: Assuming that you aren't writing a driver, most kernels (including Microsoft Windows NT, Unix (e.g. BSD), XNU (macOS) and Linux) automatically deallocate any allocated memory as the program exits.